# Transposed table redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to transpose columns into rows (without using UNION):

```
|Dimension1 | Measure1 | Measure2 |
-----------------------------------
|     1     |   x1     |  y1      |
|     0     |   x2     |  y2      |
```

Into:

```
   | Dimension1 |  Measures |  Values |
   -----------------------------------
   | 1          |  Measure1 |    x1   |
   | 1          |  Measure2 |    y1   |
   | 0          |  Measure1 |    x2   |
   | 0          |  Measure2 |    y2   |
```

The number of the measure is fixed.

I'm using Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Union for that. Why don't you want to use it ? There is no other way.